# Clear old cache data with robospice ormlite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, robospice

I used the ormlite to cache sqlite database with `Robospice`. The data after caching look like:

table **cacheentry** (generated by robospice)

```
rowid  cachekey      resultclass            resultIntegerId      timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1      113     com.sq.src.EventResult            3             1381938044268
```

table **EventResult**

```
id     data     timestamp
-------------------------
1       121    1381938211268
2       122    1381938444278
3       123    1481938785422
```

When time is expired, robospice will request and add new row data to `EventResult`.
The problem is I want to clear only old data (**clear rows id 1, 2 and keep row id 3**) from `EventResult` which this one:

```
getSpiceManager().removeDataFromCache(EventResult.class,113);
```

But it cleared only cache key row from `cacheentry` table.
And this one cleard all data from all tables.

```
 getSpiceManager().removeAllDataFromCache();
```

Could you please tell me how to control clear only old data and keep newest one in table with robospice? Thanks in advance.

**Update**: The `EventResult` has been referenced by many other tables, and I have to clear all reference rows from them.